# Automatically canceled android in app purchases, reason "other"

Tags: android

How is it possible for android in app purchases to be canceled? I have a heap of canceled in app purchased (on my Google wallet merchant account) with the reason "other". The payment is always accepted to why are they being canceled? (I'm not canceling them) Thanks :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about google wallet policies and terminology.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

People requested to refund or most cases it's because credit card not valid

Comment: I didn't think it was possible for customers to request refunds for in so purchases? (Unless they contact me personally). The credit cards have always been accepted and it says the payment succeeds.

Comment: Well, I guess you have unusual condition. I was trying to help but what I got is -1 reputation. You are right, people here really want perfect question so this topic is clear and related. So be careful next time

Comment: Well unfortunately i cant up vote until i get 15 rep (no chance... Ill be looking for a new account soon enough haha) but thanks for trying to help rather than shoot down my question because you didn't like my wording or thought i was stupid to ask. Can't say I've ever gotten any of my questions answered.